# msbuild scripts having problem with silverlight app

Tags: .net, silverlight, msbuild

Ok. here's my scenario.
On the build server I run the clean and build which seems to work fine. The same thing on the local doesn't work.

The breaking point somewhere in the build process is the place where Project.Web gets the calls to GetXapOutputFile() to the Silverlight project (the one with xap file) and when it tries to build the xap file project it can't find its dependencies and fails the build.
Differences between two builds boils down to these lines

Project "FinalVersion\Src\Client.Web\Client.Web.csproj" (3:3) is building "Client\Client\ConsoleClient.csproj" (18:2) on node 0 (GetXapOutputFile target(s)).
  Primary reference "Client.Messages".
      Could not find dependent files. Expected file "Client.Messages\bin\Build\Client.Messages.dll" does not exist.

And the other one(in the build server) finds this references and goes ahead..

Answer (score 0):

This is a total shot in the dark, but you might like to check that you have exactly the same version of Silverlight on the two machines, by examining the version number in "c:\program files\microsoft silverlight".

Answer (score 0):

Here's another shot in the dark: I had a similar problem when building my solution (containing multiple projects) via TeamCity. It turned out that the particular project which causes the problem was not set to be built in the configuration manager for the particular configuration/platform.

Verify that all "build checkboxes" are checked in Visual Studio's Configuration Manager for the *particular solution configuration and solution platform* that is used during the automated build (eg Release|x64).